# Predicting a probability of a sentence using tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, language-model

I am using this pre-trained [model of tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/lm_1b/) and trying to get a probability of a sentence. My primary task is, out of several sentences find a sentence with the largest probability.

I am able to predict next words, using this code.

```
bazel-bin/lm_1b/lm_1b_eval --mode sample \
                           --prefix "I love that I" \
                           --pbtxt data/graph-2016-09-10.pbtxt \
                           --vocab_file data/vocab-2016-09-10.txt  \
                           --ckpt 'data/ckpt-*'
```

However, how can I get a probability of a sentence from a list of many sentences?